# "Single" Entry page gives 404, even though it's enabled

Tags: entries, 404, live-preview, singles

I added a new `Single` Entry on my site and populated it with content. When I try to access it at the URL I set, it only returns a 404 error, as if the page were disabled. It's not disabled, though. I also noticed that `Live Preview` also doesn't show up on the right side as it usually does when I edit this page; is that somehow related?

As far as I can tell, the page should be publicly accessible by all rights. I've set the URI correctly and every other setting that I know of. When I look under `All entries`, it gives me a clickable URI for my page as if it should work, but when I click this link, I get an inexplicable 404.

I'm using Craft CMS 2.6.3019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was occurring because I didn't have a template file for the page in question. I added it under `/craft/templates/`. All I had to do was copy another template used for news articles and adapt it to my specific page requirements. Then the page showed up flawlessly, as did the `Live Preview` button.